# Firebase Function Returning [Error: NOT FOUND]

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

Im using `"@react-native-firebase/functions": "^18.6.2",` within my app. I am receiving the above error when trying to call a callable function. My function is not hitting the server.

```
import functions from "@react-native-firebase/functions";

export const createSubscription = async (customer, price, callback) => {
  await functions()
    .httpsCallable("createSubscription")({
      customer_id: customer,
      price_id: price,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        callback(response.data);
        return;
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("CATCH ERROR:", error);
      return;
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried importing the Installation steps provided as shown on:
https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage#installation


If you are running an expo app you will need to run `npx expo prebuild` to get android & ios files and then 



If so then maybe you will need to run this on ios:
`cd ios`
`pod install`

On android you use this installation: https://rnfirebase.io/functions/usage/installation/android

Please let me know if you have done these steps then I will try help.